# CodeMirror converts two chars to single unicode char (eg >= to ≥)

Tags: codemirror

As of lately my CodeMirror component started converting greather than or equal to operators to single unicode sign, eg:

```
 >= to ≥
 != to ≠
```

Since I'm writing program code I do NOT want that.
I went through config options and don't see where did I turn it on.

This is how the component is instantiated:

```
CodeMirror.fromTextArea(elem, {
        lineNumbers: true,
        indentUnit: 4,
        mode: "text/x-csrc",
        theme: "ambiance",
        readOnly: false
    })
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not a font like Fira Code?

Comment: It is, you're right. I've learned a new word today - "ligature".
Apparently, it can be controlled via CSS.
I'll add the answer for the posterity.

Comment: Realized since this is what your question looks like on my PC: https://i.imgur.com/9of8LIa.png :)

Answer (score 2):

It is not a CodeMirror thing, it is a font feature - ligature:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature

It can be controlled via CSS:

```
font-variant-ligatures: none;
```

It has been proposed that CodeMirror has this setting as default:
https://github.com/codemirror/CodeMirror/issues/3899